# Fabric js object corners out of position when stroke width is increased @ run time

Tags: fabricjs

I am creating a visual tool shapes using fabric js. I got stuck on fixing the corners position when i increase the stroke with on runtime from a button. I am drawing a rectangle. Here is my code :

rectangle.setStrokeWidth(swidth);
 canvas.renderall().

Need help please. Thank you.

Comment: The code you gave is not enough to reproduce the problem you are facing. Can you create a jsfiddle or post some code here?

Comment: Its ok now. I have already solved it. I just need to parse to int the value from spinner button. Thanks.